# 408 on nodejs firebase functions call from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, firebase

I have a firebase project and I started to work with firebase functions: [their official docs.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)

But basically, from what I understood in a nutshell firebase functions lets you write some nodejs code to work as a backend on their cloud hosting server as functions. So, I have a button that have to send onClick startdate and enddate from a calendar pick (I tested on the console, it will take the desired format in UNIX format), here is the code:

```
$("#get_excel_button").click(function() {
    var startdate = moment($("#filter_date_from").val(), "D MMMM, YYYY").unix();
    var enddate = moment($("#filter_date_to").val(), "D MMMM, YYYY").unix();
    $.ajax({
    url: 'my-generated-function-url-after-deploy.cloudfunctions.net/getAjax',
    data: '{startdate: startdate, enddate: enddate}',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        var ret = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $('#lblResponse').html(ret.msg);
        console.log('Success: ')
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
        $('#lblResponse').html('Error connecting to the server.');
    },
});
});
```

That ajax have to POST on this node.js firebase function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.getAjax = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    var date = '';
    var startdate = '';
    var enddate = '';
    request.on('data', function(data) 
    {
        date += JSON.parse(data);
    });
    request.on('end', function() 
    {  console.log(date);
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/json");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.end(store);
    });
 });
```

But when I try to send that ajax I will get a status code: 408 on the getAjax, why I get a timeout?

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the HTTP functions like `send();`, `redirect();` or `end();` to complete the request and send it.

Without this function, the server will  force the open connection to close as 408 code.

I doubt you placed  `request.on('end', function() {response.end(store); })` since you don't get status code from response before to end it.

Try this code `response.status(200).end();` not inside of `request.on();` It must be inside of `functions.https.onRequest();`

EDIT:

About CORS...

```
// Enable CORS using the `cors` express middleware.
cors(req, res, () => {
  // ...
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events

Comment: Now I will get: XMLHttpRequest cannot load my-generated-function-url-after-deploy.cloudfunctions.net/getAjax. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. So it's the CORS problem, but it's weird cause on the Network I will get 202 now from node, hmmm.

Comment: See my edited answer,  I dont know what's 202, I guess you should replace functions with cors();